# Android GridView not showing items

Tags: android, gridview, android-imageview, android-gridview

I have made an app with a gridview by following slidenerd's [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8NoHxfIu0MQ).  My problem is that I can see the view but it's empty. When I move my finger I can see the top and the button becoming blue. 
Here is my code:
**The Adapter:**

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<SingleButton> buttons;
    private MainActivity mainActivity;

    public GridViewAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity) {
        this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
        this.buttons = new ArrayList<SingleButton>();

        Resources res = mainActivity.getApplicationContext().getResources();
        String[] temp = res.getStringArray(R.array.buttons);
        int[] buttonImages = { R.drawable.pic1, R.drawable.pic2,
                R.drawable.pic3, R.drawable.pic4, R.drawable.pic5,
                R.drawable.pic6, R.drawable.pic7, R.drawable.pic8,
                R.drawable.pic9 };

        for (int count = 0; count < 9; ++count) {
            this.buttons
                    .add(new SingleButton(buttonImages[count], temp[count]));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.buttons.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return this.buttons.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @SuppressLint("ViewHolder")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mainActivity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_button, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(row);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        holder.buttonImage.setImageResource(buttons.get(position).image);
        holder.buttonText.setText(buttons.get(position).buttonText);

        return row;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        ImageView buttonImage;
        TextView buttonText;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            this.buttonImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageViewButton);
            this.buttonText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewButton);
        }
    }

    class SingleButton {
        int image;
        String buttonText;

        SingleButton(int image, String buttonText) {
            this.image = image;
            this.buttonText = buttonText;
        }
    }
```

**single_button.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:maxLines="1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**main activity layout:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    tools:context="com.example.app.MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewLogo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/company_logo" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridViewButtons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageViewLogo"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:stretchMode="spacingWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
    </GridView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post the single_button.xml code? And also the layout that includes the gridview.

Comment: I think you need to provide a android:columnWidth value for your gridview, because, unfortunately, android does not automatically attribute a width to the columns.